# Select entries where Date Difference not higher than 5 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a SQL Statement which gives me all Entries whoms Date are not more than 5 days apart from another entry in this Table.

Example:

```
ID | Date

1  | 16.10.14 00:00:00
2  | 14.10.14 00:00:00
3  | 09.09.14 00:00:00
4  | 13.10.14 00:00:00
5  | 06.07.14 00:00:00
6  | 09.01.14 00:00:00
7  | 10.01.14 00:00:00
8  | 14.05.14 00:00:00
```

Expected Output:

```
ID | Date

1  | 16.10.14 00:00:00
2  | 14.10.14 00:00:00 
4  | 13.10.14 00:00:00
6  | 09.01.14 00:00:00
7  | 10.01.14 00:00:00
8  | 14.01.14 00:00:00
```

EDIT:

In fact all I need is a way to do a diff over the datatype `Date`. That's why I cant even show my attempts cause I'm missing the keyword.

Nevermind I will still try

It should be something like this:

```
select * from example m where m.Date  not more apart than 5 days from another entry in the Table
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please show what attempt you have made.

Comment: Where is the other table data?

Comment: @ti im sorry if my Question looks like I didnt put any effort in researching. All i need in fact is the method in SQL to do a diff over the date, thats why I didnt elaborate the Question with so much overhead Simple Question Simple Answer. I dont know the Answer others do.

Comment: @pradeep in the same table

Comment: @ti edited, should match ure requirements now ;)

Comment: BTW: `date` is a reserved word in [tag:oracle] - you cannot call a column that name, unless you use quotes. And even then, it's probably a bad idea.

Comment: @mureinik was just a dummyname for the question, thanks for the hint anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` operator, when applied on two `date`s, will return their difference in **days**. So, you can use the `exists` operator to construct your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table o
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   my_table i
               WHERE  ABS (o.my_date - i.my_date) <= 5)
```

Comment: oh thats cool, didnt know that dates can be compared with a - operator, thougt it has to be a very complex SQL.... Thank you